# VMplayer not enough memory after upgrade to 17.10 (artful aardvark)

Tags: vmware, 17.10

After upgrading to Artful, I can not get any virtual machine to work in VMplayer and when I try to run any of my old machines I get this message :

> Not enough physical memory is available to power on this virtual machine with its configured settings.
>   It is possible that native applications and/or services have locked down memory which could be preventing the virtual machine from launching. Shutting down unnecessary applications or services may free enough memory to launch this virtual machine.
>   If you were able to power on this virtual machine on this host computer in the past, try rebooting the host computer. Rebooting may allow you to use slightly more host memory to run virtual machines.

N.B: Memory usage : 2.74G/7.67 (I have 8G of memory).

After that message is displayed the VMplayer crashes.

I have done some research in the Internet but most posts are treating this problem in Windows.
I tried this few solutions:

- Searched for .lck files to remove them, find none.
- Searched for .vmss files find and remove them all.
- Edited all my .vmx files go to section `checkpoint.vmState = ""`, and remove text between quotes.
- And finally uninstall, purge and reinstall application. To unistall I find this command : `sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player` because `sudo apt-get remove VMplayer` didn't do anything, and to reinstall i downloaded and ran the latest version : `VMware-Player-14.0.0-6661328.x86_64.bundle`.
- Create new virtual machine.

None of the above solution seems to fix the problem, I am stuck with VirtualBox which I can't get USB to work again.

Comment: How much memory are you attempting to allocate to the VM?

Comment: Generally 1Gig, cause i use it to run Win Seven 32bits for compatibility reasons.
Also, I can launch 3 or 4 virtual machines before upgrading, and i didn't change any of the configurations.
I found this problem very popular in Windows, so I found lot of workarounds, changing some configuration files in VMplayer which I cannot find in Ubuntu, starting as administrator which I tried by launching VMplayer in SU mode, but it can't be helped, nothing works for me.

Comment: Did you find a solution eventually? I have the same problem, and the provided answer also does not work for me (same error as you mentioned in the comments)

Comment: I am stuck, since my upgrade to artful, neither vmplayer nor kile live preview are working, neither the compilation solution worked for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/969086/323511) method, I've used the following commands to solve similar issue:

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules.git
cd vmware-host-modules
git checkout workstation-14.0.0
tar cf vmmon.tar vmmon-only
sudo cp vmmon.tar /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

In this way it compiles and works correctly.

Comment: When running a script containing these lines I got the same error.
When trying to run the same script with `sudo` command the compilation is "O.K" and I got my problem solved.

Comment: vmware-modconfig --console --install-all gives an error like "Failed to get gcc information. " on my computer

Comment: maybe you don't have installation tools. use `apt-get install build-essential` to install necessary packages.

Comment: I am having the same issue, but the build-essentials are installed.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here's how you do this: After installing VM Workstation Player 14 in Ubuntu 17.10, download this proper diff'd patch and save it to /tmp/hostif-fix.patch

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/geneC/936e4caf6963f3dea99131aa31f004ea/raw/bd87148030746126d744ae694f5a5e43c9faf06c/hostif-fix.patch

Run the following as root (manually with sudo su, or in a .sh file run with sudo sh):

```
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
tar xf vmmon.tar
cd vmmon-only/linux
patch hostif.c /tmp/hostif-fix.patch
cd ../..
tar cf vmmon.tar vmmon-only
rm -rf vmmon-only 
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Works, tested on Ubuntu 17.10 with Workstation Player 14. Thanks to geneC for creating the working patch, and to Charles Green for identifying the original commit and procedure

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a known issue with kernel 14.0 and above - there is a patch available at https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/commit/770c7ffe611520ac96490d235399554c64e87d9f

Instructions (adapted from Arch Linux)

```
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
tar xf vmmon.tar
cd vmmon-only/linux
vim hostif.c # or use the patch command to apply the patch
cd ../..
tar cf vmmon.tar vmmon-only
rm -rf vmmon-only # cleanup

# Lastly, we need to rebuild the patched module
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Some references:

[vmware community](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/573281)

[superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1255099/vmware-workstation-not-enough-physical-memory-since-last-update)

[A Windows host based VMWare solution](https://www.petri.com/fixing-enough-physical-memory-available-errors-vmware-workstation)

Comment: Can't compile, got this error :  
`/tmp/modconfig-79T7MO/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:99:10: fatal error: vmmonInt.h: No such file or directory
 #include "vmmonInt.h"`

Comment: K  - you're probably going to need to go to the source on GitHub to get a better resolution on this - from what I read, they seem pretty active.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue - thanks @CharlesGreen for the answer!

As I'm running Workstation Player 14.0.0 simply replacing the file with the referenced patch won't do.

You have to actually replace the code in the extracted `hostif.c`. The referenced Patch was supplied for Workstation Player 12.5 and wont work for 14

Comment: That's exactly what I've done, and after replacing text in `hostif.c`, you have to compile again and there I got this error message :  
`/tmp/modconfig-79T7MO/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:99:10: fatal error: vmmonInt.h: No such file or directory #include "vmmonInt.h`.

Comment: to be very clear on this: have you replaced the entire content oh `hostif.c` or did you apply the the single changes of the patch?

Comment: I replaced the entire content.

Comment: Only apply the sections changed in the referenced file. 
The referenced file is ment for Workstation Player 14 - it WILL NOT WORK with 14.
The changes on the other hand will.

[here](https://gist.github.com/chillinger/cf6039a846c287caa8d97cf30a9986a5) you find the file for Player 14 with the changes already applied